# Package restore fails when installing EntityFramework 6.1.3 in Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to install the EntityFramework 6.1.3 (latest stable version) dependency in a .NETStandard 1.4 class library but I keep getting a Package restore failed error.  I get the same error with previous versions of EntityFramework (I tried everything back to v6.1.0).  I've tried restarting Visual Studio and restarting the VM I'm running it in to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the entity framework core with .net standard not entity framework 6

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/